# Sphinx: Is there a way to read yaml file by sphinx and generate HTML page?

Tags: yaml, python-sphinx

I am new to Sphinx. There is a requirement to show the service dependencies of an application by consuming its pom.xml. I am looking for a way to do it by Sphinx.

Things I have tried:

1. Converting pom.xml to a corresponding YAML file and try to create HTML by sphinx using the docfx extension added to conf.py.
2. I have also searched for an extension to convert XML to HTML directly.

Comment: Sphinx reads and parses reStructuredText. If you can export your file to reST, then you can use Sphinx to generate HTML.

Comment: By consuming i mean that I need to extract only the dependency tga from it. We use external repository as a dependent jars. Hence, we need to document the dependent jars. I have extracted that using a python code into a yaml. But sphinx is unable to parse that yaml into html. Though i can parse openApi yamls using one extension of sphinx. Parsing a random yaml is the issue of the hour.

Comment: "Parsing a random yaml is the issue of the hour." Have you tried PyYAML? https://pyyaml.org/